# How to find: $\int^{2\pi}_0 (1+\cos(x))\cos(x)(-\sin^2(x)+\cos(x)+\cos^2(x))~dx$?

Tags: integration

How to find: $$\int^{2\pi}_0 (1+\cos(x))\cos(x)(-\sin^2(x)+\cos(x)+\cos^2(x))~dx$$

I tried multiplying it all out but I just ended up in a real mess and I'm wondering if there is something I'm missing.

Comment: Have you tried using $\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)=\cos(2x)$ and just integrating?

Comment: Good call I forgot about that identity.

Comment: Would I need to use parts?

Comment: Definitely, since you're essentially going to end up having integrands which are powers of $\cos$, which can be handled by integration by parts.

Comment: Could we possibly switch the cosines with complex exponentials and consider the real part of the final result we get or will there be more terms than we desire hanging around, @Moya?

Comment: depending on what you are willing to use you could try solving it via complex analytic methods as for example described here: http://mathfaculty.fullerton.edu/mathews/c2003/integralstrigmod.html

Answer (score 4):

$\displaystyle\int_0^{2\pi}(\cos x+\cos^2x)(\cos 2x+\cos x)dx=\int_0^{2\pi}\big(\cos x+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\cos 2x\big)\big(\cos 2x+\cos x\big)dx$

$\displaystyle\int_0^{2\pi}\big(\cos x\cos 2x+\cos^{2}x+\frac{1}{2}\cos 2x+\frac{1}{2}\cos x+\frac{1}{2}\cos^{2} 2x+\frac{1}{2}\cos 2x\cos x\big)dx$

$\displaystyle\int_0^{2\pi}\big(\frac{3}{2}\cos x\cos 2x+\frac{1}{2}+\cos 2x+\frac{1}{2}\cos x+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{4}\cos 4x\big)dx$

$\displaystyle\int_0^{2\pi}\big(\frac{3}{4}(\cos 3x+\cos x)+\frac{3}{4}+\cos 2x+\frac{1}{2}\cos x+\frac{1}{4}\cos4x\big)dx=\frac{3}{4}(2\pi)=\frac{3\pi}{2}$

(since $\sin n\pi=0$ for any integer n)

Answer (score 2):

You have to linearise the integrand. The simplest way to do is with Euler's formulae. To shorten the computation, set $u=\mathrm e^{\mathrm ix}$. Starting with $\cos x =\dfrac{u+\bar u}2$ and taking into account the relations 
$$u\bar u=1,\quad u^n+\bar u^n=2\cos nx,$$
we have
\begin{align*}
(1+\cos x)&\cos x(-\sin^2x+\cos x+\cos^2x)=(1+\cos x)\cos x(\cos x+\cos 2x)\\
&=\Bigl(1+\frac{u+\bar u}2\Bigr)\frac{u+\bar u}2\Bigl(\frac{u+\bar u}2+\frac{u^2+\bar u^2}2\Bigr)\\
&=\frac18(2+u+\bar u)(u+\bar u)\bigl(u+\bar u+u^2+\bar u^2\bigr)\\
&=\frac18\bigr(u^4+\bar u^4+3(u^3+\bar u^3)+4(u^2+\bar u^2)+5(u+\bar u)+6\bigl)\\
&=\frac14(\cos 4x+3\cos 3x+4\cos 2x+5\cos x+3)
\end{align*}
Consequently the  integral from $0$ to $2\pi$ is equal to
$$\frac{3\pi}2.$$

Answer (score 1):

try to show that the integrand is equivalent to $$\frac{1}{4} (7 \cos (x)+4 \cos (2 x)+\cos (3 x)+4)$$

Comment: There must be an error in your computation: the integral is not equal to $2\pi$, and there should be terms in $4x$ since the expression is a polynomial of total degree $4$ in $\sin x$ and $\cos x$.

Comment: yes sorry my result of the calculation again

Comment: $$\frac{1}{4} (5 \cos (x)+4 \cos (2 x)+3 \cos (3 x)+\cos (4 x)+3) $$